# How to remove widget in Kivy and then create again?

Tags: kivy

I am using Kivy and Kivymd.
There is a class `Detail` in my code where I am creating a card. I need to remove any card before creating a new card.

I have a func `remove`. I can use it to remove any cards, then create a new card. But I need to implement removing and creating in one func `add`.

My py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Detail(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def add(self, instance):
        # self.remove()
        article = self.ids.article.text
        card = MDCard(size_hint=(None, None), padding=20)
        my_label = MDLabel(text=article)
        card.add_widget(my_label)
        self.ids.box.add_widget(card)

    def remove(self):
        self.ids.boxlayout_1.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Detail())

class Container(Screen):
    pass

class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

App().run()
```

my app.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    Container:
        name: 'container'
    Detail:
        name: 'detail'

<Container>
    MDRaisedButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        text: 'Go To Detail'
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'detail'

<Detail>
    BoxLayout:
        id: boxlayout_1
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'App'

        Button:
            id: btn
            text: 'Remove Cards'
            on_release: root.remove()

        MDTextField:
            id: article
            hint_text: 'Input article'
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            mode: 'rectangle'

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: me
            text: 'add'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_release: root.add(root)

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                spacing: 5
                id: box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `remove()` method is removing more than just the cards. Try changing it to just remove the `Widgets` in the `MDList`, like this:

```
def remove(self):
    self.ids.box.clear_widgets()
```

Then the `add()` method can just call `remove()`, like this:

```
def add(self, instance):
    self.remove()
    article = self.ids.article.text
    card = MDCard(size_hint=(None, None), padding=20)
    my_label = MDLabel(text=article)
    card.add_widget(my_label)
    self.ids.box.add_widget(card)
```